# Comparison and Extraction using SSE

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd

What is the best way for pairwise comparison of two integer registers and extraction of equal elements using SSE instructions? For example, if `a = [6 4 7 2]` and `b = [2 4 9 2]` (each register contains four 32-bit integers), the  result should be `[4 2 x x]`. An alternative form of this question is how to obtain a binary mask of equal elements (`..0101b`) that can be used for shuffling or as an index to lookup a parameter for shuffling instruction in the precomputed table.

Comment: Subtraction will turn equal pairs of numbers into 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use a variant of what `drhirsch` proposes:

```
int index = _mm_movemask_ps((__m128)_mm_cmp_epi32(a, b));
```

This gives you the same index to use in looking up a shuffle mask using only two operations.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to extract and move equal elements with one instruction. But a mask of equal elements can easily be achieved with `pcmpeqd`:

```
__m128i zero = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
__m128i a = _mm_set_epi32(6, 4, 7, 2);
__m128i b = _mm_set_epi32(2, 4, 9, 2);

__m128i mask = _mm_cmp_epi32(a, b);     // mask is now 0, -1, 0, -1
mask = _mm_sub_epi32(zero, mask);       // mask is now 0,  1, 0,  1
```

Edit:
If you want some index for a lookup table with shuffle constants, you need additional operations. Like

```
static const __m128i zero = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
static const __m128i bits = _mm_set_epi32(1,2,4,8);

__m128i a = _mm_set_epi32(6, 4, 7, 2);
__m128i b = _mm_set_epi32(2, 4, 9, 2);

__m128i bitvector = _mm_and_si128(bits, _mm_cmp_epi32(a, b));
bitvector = _mm_hadd_epi32(bitvector, bitvector);
bitvector = _mm_hadd_epi32(bitvector, bitvector);
// now a index from 0...15 is the the low 32 bit of bitvector
```

There might be better algorithms than using a lookup table for computing the shuffle, possibly calculating the shuffle directly using a De Bruijn mulitiplication. OTOH if you have more than 4 ints to compare, additional 4 int's would only come at the cost of *one* additional `phaddd`.

Comment: I actually meant a bit mask that can be used in shuffling instruction directly or as a small index to lookup a mask in the precomputed table, i.e. in this example `mask = ..0101b = 5d`.